Reason: Input dispatching timed out .MainActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 8001ms for MotionEvent(action=DOWN)) -ANR
I got Below Error while interact with the screen android Application.
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (com.package/com.package.main.MainActivity, 
307432d com.package.botree/com.package.main.MainActivity (server) is not responding. 
Waited 8001ms for MotionEvent(action=DOWN))
                                                                                                
Parent: com.package.botree/com.package.main.MainActivity

  ** Load: 27.45 / 25.92 / 25.55
                                                                                                ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=147729045
                                                                                                full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=70702460
                                                                                                ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                
                                                                                                CPU usage from 9552ms to 0ms ago (2024-10-09 19:14:14.214 to 2024-10-09 19:14:23.766):
                                                                                                  21% 1482/system_server: 15% user + 6.3% kernel / faults: 20155 minor
                                                                                                  17% 792/surfaceflinger: 10% user + 7.4% kernel / faults: 393 minor
                                                                                                  16% 727/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 3% user + 13% kernel / faults: 1198 minor
                                                                                                  14% 2107/com.android.systemui: 9.4% user + 5.3% kernel / faults: 2955 minor
                                                                                                  13% 19660/android.process.media: 11% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 9160 minor
                                                                                                  11% 716/android.hardware.audio.service.mediatek: 11% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 191 minor
                                                                                                  11% 996/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.2-service: 10% user + 1.2% kernel
                                                                                                  10% 22604/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 8.4% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 757 minor
                                                                                                  4.6% 10234/com.android.settings: 3.7% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 3427 minor
                                                                                                  3.9% 981/mediaserver: 2.3% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 772 minor
                                                                                                  2.9% 731/android.hardware.sensors@2.0-service.multihal-mediatek: 1.3% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                                                                  2.5% 4754/com.mi.android.globalminusscreen: 1.7% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 656 minor
                                                                                                  2.2% 1030/media.swcodec: 1.2% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 209 minor
                                                                                                  2.2% 7408/com.android.bluetooth: 1.4% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 268 minor
                                                                                                  1.9% 775/audioserver: 1.4% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 138 minor
                                                                                                  1.9% 19607/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 1.8% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3522 minor
                                                                                                  1.8% 459/logd: 1.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 5 minor
                                                                                                  1.5% 2148/com.android.networkstack.process: 1.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 1211 minor
                                                                                                  1.4% 963/mnld: 1% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                                                                  1.3% 460/lmkd: 0.1% user + 1.2% kernel
                                                                                                  1.3% 24395/com.miui.msa.global: 1.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 378 minor
                                                                                                  1.2% 8456/kworker/u16:6: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
                                                                                                  1.2% 14163/kworker/u17:3: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
                                                                                                  1.1% 306/irq/39-5-0034: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
                                                                                                  1.1% 4053/com.miui.securitycenter.remote: 0.9% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1146 minor
                                                                                                  0.9% 2254/com.android.phone: 0.6% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 263 minor
                                                                                                  0.9% 12341/kworker/u17:1: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
                                                                                                  0.9% 14248/kworker/u16:2: 0% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                                                                  0.8% 711/statsd: 0.5% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 11 minor
                                                                                                  0.8% 8096/kworker/u16:0: 0% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                                                                  0.8% 22447/com.google.android.gms: 0.6% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 274 minor
                                                                                                  0.7% 429/ueventd: 0.6% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.6% 5164/com.miui.powerkeeper: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 134 minor
                                                                                                  0.6% 12727/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
                                                                                                  0.5% 132/ion_mm_heap_for: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                                                                  0.5% 215/chre_kthread: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 3339/com.google.android.providers.media.module: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 44 minor
                                                                                                  0.1% 14291/kworker/u16:7: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 8 minor
                                                                                                  0.5% 26397/com.xiaomi.bluetooth: 0.4% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 101 minor
                                                                                                  0.4% 199/pbm: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                                                                  0.4% 365/charger_thread: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                                                                  0.4% 527/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 21 minor
                                                                                                  0.4% 717/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-service-mediatek: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.4% 979/media.extractor: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 53 minor
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.3% 722/android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-mediatek: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.3% 726/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@4.0-service-mediatek: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 444 minor
                                                                                                  0.3% 1375/mtkfusionrild: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.3% 1942/main_thread: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                  0.3% 1943/hif_thread: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0% 127/dlpt_notify_thr: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 158/kswapd0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 200/btif_rxd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 271/disp_delay_trig: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 461/servicemanager: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 728/android.hardware.health@2.1-service: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 740/vendor.mediatek.hardware.mtkpower@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 978/keystore: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 288 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 980/media.metrics: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 96 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 985/storaged: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 1936/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service-lazy: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 2608/com.miui.home: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 31 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 2863/com.xiaomi.xmsf: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 16 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 12548/com.xiaomi.mipicks: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 19 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 12831/kworker/u16:4: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 13658/com.google.process.gapps: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 184 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 14095/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                  0.2% 14165/com.botree.productsfa.botree: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 48 minor
                                                                                                  0.2% 14905/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 14 minor
                                                                                                  0% 34/migration/5: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 259/teei_switch_thr: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0% 261/teei_log_thread: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 273/present_fence_w: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 427/init: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 462/hwservicemanager: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 528/android.hardware.keymaster@4.0-service.beanpod: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 712/netd: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor
                                                                                                  0.1% 733/android.hardware.usb@1.1-service-mediatek: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 18 minor
                                                                                                  0% 746/vendor.xiaomi.hardware.micharge@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 36 minor
                                                                                                  0.1% 796/fuelgauged: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 933/mtk_stp_psm: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 935/mtk_wmtd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0% 995/mtk_agpsd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 1944/rx_thread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0% 2144/ip6tables-restore: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2 minor
                                                                                                  0.1% 2864/com.miui.aod: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 11 minor
                                                                                                  0% 2978/charge_logger: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0% 3459/com.miui.daemon: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                                                                  0% 5201/com.xiaomi.joyose: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 15 minor
                                                                                                  0% 6545/kworker/7:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 12218/kworker/5:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 12326/kworker/4:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 12726/kworker/2:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                  0.1% 12744/com.google.android.projection.gearhead:car: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                                                                                                  0.1% 23836/com.miui.notification:remote: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 23 minor
                                                                                                  0% 26266/com.xiaomi.location.fused: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
                                                                                                 +0% 14720/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                23% TOTAL: 13% user + 9% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.1% softirq
                                                                                                CPU usage from 38ms to 471ms later (2024-10-09 19:14:23.804 to 2024-10-09 19:14:24.237):
                                                                                                  44% 1482/system_server: 0% user + 44% kernel / faults: 673 minor
                                                                                                    38% 14734/AnrConsumer: 14% user + 23% kernel
                                                                                                  11% 996/vendor.mediatek.hardware.pq@2.2-service: 8.5% user + 2.8% kernel
                                                                                                    11% 1173/AALMain: 8.5% user + 2.8% kernel
                                                                                                  8.2% 22604/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 8.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
                                                                                                    4.1% 22680/FlpThread: 4.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                    4.1% 22819/NearbyDiscovery: 4.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                  2.3% 40/ksoftirqd/6: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
                                                                                                  2.3% 215/chre_kthread: 0% user + 2.3% kernel
                                                                                                  
2.4% 271/disp_delay_trig: 0% user + 2.4% kernel**

 **Due to this app got freeze and ANR occurred**

